# Ruby: What is this error referring to? wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it referring to `sid, ip_src, ip_dst`? Line 148 starts with `look_for'

I'm trying to use these parameters to remove duplicate ips alerts. If I only have one alert to display I do not get this error. As soon as I have 2 or more alerts I get this error.

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:148:in `[]'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in index'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:147:in `uniq'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:147:in `block in index'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:131:in `each'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:131:in `index'
```

|Added for further explanation|

Index View:

```
<% if @filtered_snort_detail_query.count > 0 %>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Tag Info</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
      <% @filtered_snort_detail_query.each do |d|
        text_msg = d['_source']['message']
        if d['_source']['message'].nil?
        end
      %>
          <tr>
            <td class='timestamp'><%= d['_source']['@timestamp'].to_time %></td>
            <td class='tags'><%= d['_source']['tags'] %></td>
            <td class='message'><%= text_msg %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>

    </table>
<% else %>
    <div> No Results Returned. </div>
<% end %>
```

|Added for further explanation|

When I use this code in the controller I receive all alerts from the IPS in my view:
Doing it this way, I may receive 500 alerts that could be condensed down to 1 alert based in the signature ID (sid), Source IP (ip_src), and Destination IP (ip_dst).

```
if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail)
      end
 end
```

This is my attempt to remove duplicate alerts using `sid, ip_src, ip_dst` in the controller but this code throws the error:

```
    if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      sid = Array.new
      ip_src = Array.new
      ip_dst = Array.new
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        if ips_detail['_source']['message'].nil?
          text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
        else
          text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
        end
        unless text_msg.nil?
          sid_data = text_msg.scan(/\[\d+:\d+:\d+\]/)
          src_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          dst_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          sid.push(sid_data[0]) unless sid_data[0].nil?
          ip_src.push(src_ip_data[0]) unless src_ip_data[0].nil?
          ip_dst.push(dst_ip_data[1]) unless dst_ip_data[1].nil?

          @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail).uniq do |look_for|
            look_for[{:ips_info => sid}, {:ips_info => ip_src}, {:ips_info => ip_dst}]
          end
        end
      end
      end
```

Comment: It's just a name I use in `@filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail).uniq do |look_for|`

Comment: This `look_for[{:ips_info => sid}, {:ips_info => ip_src}, {:ips_info => ip_dst}]` syntax doesn't look good to me. What are you trying to do here? `look_for` will be element of this @filtered_snort_detail_query array.

Comment: @insecure-IT - so is it an array (looks like it), hash, some other object you implemented `[]` method on? What do you expect this call to return?

Comment: I'm trying to use this to remove duplicate alerts. `sid, ip_src, and ip_dst` are the .scan results of my alerts, and is what I need to use to display only unique alerts.

Comment: @BroiSatse, its first called at `@filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail).uniq do |look_for|`, I'm only using it as a name. I don't really know what to use in the pipes in a do block, I assumed they where just names, but I must be wrong.

Comment: You are using `uniq` everytime you enter in the loop. any reason? I think it would be better you build the complete array and finally call `uniq` on it. Moreover, `uniq` will comapre the array for uniqueness based on the value of the block passed. So the statement you wrote should return some value.

Comment: @Manoj Monga, I'm just trying to remove duplicate alerts from `@filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail)`.

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample data and the result you're expecting. As your question doesn't give the clear idea what exactly the data is. Please provide some input/expected output data.

Comment: @Manoj Monga, I updated the original post, I hope this is a better explanation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `3` arguments in `look_for`:

```
look_for[{:ips_info => sid}, {:ips_info => ip_src}, {:ips_info => ip_dst}]
```

It should just be `1` argument as you are accessing a particular **index** in `look_for` array. Hence, the error.